# How to stop UISegmentedControl segments animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, ios-autolayout

Is there any way to stop the animation of the method `insertSegment(withTitle:at:animated)`? Even if I set `animated:false` the segment animates, look this:

[image: Animated gif of the bug]

*Please ignore the red ball.*

The code that I am using to create the component is:

```
let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
segmentedControl.sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
```

The constraint setup is ok, the frame width (100% - 16 pixels both sides) is the same all the time. The problem is related of the segments, not the parent view.

To add segments (this happens after a settings check):

```
segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "Bolinha 1", at: 0, animated: false)
```

Setting the frame doesn't work, since the problem is related to the inner views.

I tried to remove it using `setAnimationsEnabled(false)` but doesn't work.

Edit 1: Using `segmentedControl.setWidth(segmentedControl.frame.width/3, forSegmentAt: 0)` doesn't work.

Edit 2: Starting the view with `UISegmentedControl(items: ["", "", ""])` does it replacing the whole component, this is a very heavy solution for this problem btw...

The project uses Swift 3.1.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share a sample project?

Comment: @Pedro Paulo Amorim: How have you setup constraints in code?

Comment: @Puneet Shama I solved the problem, this is related to constraints animation. I will post the answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that a animation has modifying the behaviour of the inner components.

Removing this animation fixed the problem:

```
view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

UIView.animate(
  withDuration: 0.5,
  delay: 0.5,
  usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0,
  initialSpringVelocity: 2,
  animations: { [weak self] in
    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }, completion: nil)
```

The correct solution for this is to avoid any animation during the build of constraints.